# PHP Maximum Execution Time?

Tags: php, execution

I might be missing something in this block of code, seems like some kind of loop issue, here is the code, I can't figure out what is going on:

```
    function clearBoard() {
        //initialize board with a . in each cell
        global $board, $boardData;

        for ($row = 0; $row < $boardData["height"]; $row++) {
            for ($col = 0; $col < $boardData["width"]; $col++) {
                $board[$row][$col] = ".";
            } //end col for loop
        } //end row for loop
    } //end clearBoard
```

Thankyou much

Alex

Comment: could you print `$boardData["height"]` and `$boardData["width"]`, please?

Comment: missing array declaration?

Answer (score 2):

There is no innate problem with that code; it does the obvious thing in a very reasonable manner. If it's taking too long, then the grid is too big. It's as simple as that.

With that said, there is one way you might be able to speed it up: using [`array_fill`](http://www.php.net/array_fill):

```
function clearBoard() {
    global $board, $boardData;
    $board = array_fill(0, $boardData["height"],
        array_fill(0, $boardData["width"], "."));
}
```

`array_fill` is, as far as I know, implemented in C, which should be faster than PHP.